# How to redistribute .Net Framework

Tags: .net, visual-c++, mfc, installation

I have a Visual C++ solution. When I install it on a different machine and run, it searches for the .Net Framework. How do I include the .Net Framework in the installer itself?
I have made a simple installer using Visual studio.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a .NET Framework prerequisite:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77z6b8tz(VS.80).aspx?ppud=4
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429(VS.80).aspx?ppud=4
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429.aspx?ppud=4

This way Visual Studio will generate an EXE bootstrapper for your MSI which handles the prerequisite installation.